# variable no inicializada y expresiones no reportadas

Tags: java

Hola buen dia estoy teniendo problemas al intentar resolver los problemas de el programa que simula una maquina dispensadora de bebidas.
el problema aparece como una variable no inicializada y como expresiones no reportadas

(aun estoy comenzando a programar en Java)

Aquí esta el código:

```
package ma;
import java.io.*;

public class Ma {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader bufEntrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int cantidadvasos;
    int capacidad;
    int contenido;
    int llenar;
    int opcion;
    int servir;
    int vaciar;
    int vaso;
    opcion = 0;
    while ((opcion!=5)) {
        System.out.println("1- llenar la maquina");
        System.out.println("2- servrir vasos");
        System.out.println("3- mostrar nivel");
        System.out.println("4- vaciar maquina");
        System.out.println("5- salir");
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        if ((opcion==1)) {
            System.out.println("digite la cantidad a la que se llenara");
            llenar = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
            capacidad = llenar;
            if ((llenar>capacidad)) {
                System.out.println("la capacidad maxima es de 5000ml");
            }
        }
        if ((opcion==2)) {
            System.out.println("digite la cantidad de vasos que se llenaran");
    cantidadvasos = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
            servir = cantidadvasos*300;
        }
        if ((opcion==3)) {
        contenido = capacidad-servir;
            System.out.println("el nivel de la maquina es:"+contenido);
        }
        if ((opcion==4)) {
        vaciar = capacidad-capacidad;
            System.out.println("se vacio la maquina");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: siempre debes inicializar tus valores, en este caso, tus int inicializalos en 0.

Comment: Anque no lo.he corrido. Por lo que veo a simple.vista en tu codigo, te falta declarar la variable opción, por ejemplo podrías declararla: int opcion=0; Para futuras consultas sirve mucho si envías, el stacktrace de tu ejecución. Espero sirva la respuesta y exitos en tu aprendizaje :)

Comment: voy a intentar hacer que int sea igual a 0

Comment: realmente si lo está declarando más arriba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es correcto que siempre debes inicializar las variables, sin compilar el código realicé algunas modificaciones, con las cuales estoy segura resolverán tu problema. De igual forma, corregí algunos aspectos de lógica que encontré, sin embargo creo que tu misma puedes resolver otros, inténtalo, eso te ayudará bastante a desarrollar tu lógica de programación.

```
package ma;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Ma {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    BufferedReader bufEntrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int cantidadvasos;
    int capacidad = 5000;
    int contenido;
    int llenar = 0;
    int opcion = 0;
    int servir = 0;
    int vaciar=0;
    int vaso=0;

    while ((opcion != 5)) {
        System.out.println("1- llenar la maquina");
        System.out.println("2- servrir vasos");
        System.out.println("3- mostrar nivel");
        System.out.println("4- vaciar maquina");
        System.out.println("5- salir");
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        if ((opcion == 1)) {
            System.out.println("digite la cantidad a la que se llenara");
            llenar = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
            if (llenar > capacidad) {
                System.out.println("la capacidad maxima es de 5000ml");
            }
        }
        if ((opcion == 2)) {
            System.out.println("digite la cantidad de vasos que se llenaran");
            cantidadvasos = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
            servir = cantidadvasos * 300;
        }
        if ((opcion == 3)) {
            contenido = capacidad - servir;
            System.out.println("el nivel de la maquina es:" + contenido);
        }
        if ((opcion == 4)) {
            vaciar = capacidad - capacidad;
            System.out.println("se vacio la maquina");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda aun estaba comenzando por programar en java y estaba buscando mas información sobre las librerías y clases ya que el profesor en mi universidad no enseña mucho y hace que nos quedemos atorados en un projecto por días pero fue buena la ayuda para aprender mas  y saber en que me equivoco un saludo

Comment: De nada, cuando uno comienza a programar realmente es complicado, pero que bueno que que tomes iniciativa, esto te ayudará bastante. Hay un sin fin de información en internet, la cual debemos a provechar al máximo, apoyate de ello. Saludos!